# Drools - how do I compare a string value present in a Java Object which is present inside a List

Tags: drools

I am new to Drools and am having a tough time writing rules
Here is my data structure :

```
public class Premium{
   private List<InsuranceType> insuranceTypes;
}

public class InsuranceType {
   private String name;
}
```

So a Premium object will contain a List of Insurance types and I need to check if any of the insurance types has a name of "TPD"

Have tried the following :

```
rule "rule#3"
when
    $fact:Premium($insuranceTypes : InsuranceType(name == 'TPD'))
then
    System.out.println("Error");
end
```

However app server fails to start with the following error:

```
2021-11-30 12:16:37.004 ERROR 23500 --- [           main] 
o.d.c.k.builder.impl.AbstractKieModule   : Unable to build KieBaseModel:defaultKieBase
Unable to Analyse Expression InsuranceType(name == "TPD"):
[Error: unable to resolve method using strict-mode: com.xyz.Premium.name()]
[Near : {... InsuranceType(name == "TPD") ....}]
                       ^
[Line: 29, Column: 5] : [Rule name='rule#3']
Unable to analyze expression 'InsuranceType(name == "TPD")' : [Rule name='rule#3']
Field Reader does not exist for declaration '$insuranceTypes' in '$insuranceTypes : 
InsuranceType(name == "TPD")' in the rule 'rule#3' : [Rule name='rule#3']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume there's a public `getName` method on the InsuranceType class, and a public `getInsuranceTypes` method on the Premium class. If either of those isn't true, you need to add either getters or make those properties public.

---

Your rule was pretty close. However the problem you have is that `insuranceTypes` is a list but you were treating it as an object.

You have several options here, depending on your needs. However I'd go with the simplest, which is this:

```
rule "Example"
when
  Premium( $insuranceTypes: insuranceTypes )
  exists( InsuranceType( name == "TPD" ) from $insuranceTypes )
then
  System.out.println("Error");
end
```

In the first line, I get the insurance types and assign them to the variable `$insuranceTypes`. This variable is now the list of types.

Then in the second line, I assert that there exists at least one InsuranceType in the list that has the name "TPD".

---

Note that Drools also has a `memberOf` operator, and a `contains` operator, which come in useful when working with lists and other iterable collections. These are inverses of each other, eg. you'd do `Example( foo memberOf $someList )` or `Example( myList contains $something )`.

Comment: Thank you for the response and the additional details and explanation !

Comment: one quick question - when the above condition is satisfied , I would want to update an attribute 'category' of the InsuranceType  whose 'name' is TPD , so how do I write this in the then condition please ?

Comment: also I have a gut feel that these rules are quite difficult to read , and writing this in Java would be done in the blink of an eye Vs writing these drools rules . Either my scenario does not justify usage of drools or I have not understood the purpose of drools ! Rant over

Comment: For very simple cases, it's probably better and more readable to implement a simple if/else-if/else tree. But if you have a more complex case, or if you want to keep your business logic separate, rules are actually better. I used to maintain a service which had over 1 million rules -- I can't even _fathom_ writing an if-else statement to model that.

Comment: If you want to modify the object in working memory, you'd use the `modify` action on the right hand side. Refer to the [Drools documentation](https://docs.drools.org/latest/drools-docs/html_single/#drl-rules-THEN-con_drl-rules). Note that you'll likely want to adjust your "when" clause to check for the same property so you don't set the value needlessly (eg if you set 'category' to X, then there's no need to fire the rule if the category is _already_ X.)

Comment: I would say drools is not about different way of writing complex if statement. (as for me if statement + java static method import is at least not worse to read). Drools is about algorithms to recalculate only those rules that worth to recalculate taking into consideration input data change. Logic which do not depend on on the data which changed will not be recalculated meaning no CPU waste. This is not linear execution, like a list of if statement. And this is quite a task to implement.

Comment: Rules systems are often compared to artificial intelligence because this is how our mind works (it reacts on changes coming from different inputs, it doesn't process all information again and again, like ordinal application do when decision needs to be made on the whole set of data not on the delta only). While it is still far from AI (because there many cases where latest state of software engineering altogether is far behind the basic requirements of AI on my opinion) but this area (rules systems) is quite attractive and stands firm in some application tasks.

Comment: thanks @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas and Mike for your inputs , am running into an issue while updating , but will post that as a separate question

Comment: asked [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70193124/drools-getting-error-handle-not-found-for-object-is-it-in-working-memory]