# drools getting error : handle not found for object is it in working memory

Tags: drools

This question is in continuation to an earlier question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70163217/drools-how-do-i-compare-a-string-value-present-in-a-java-object-which-is-prese/70172078?noredirect=1#comment124070463_70172078)
so my data structure is as earlier :

```
public class Premium{
  private List<InsuranceType> insuranceTypes;
  // getter and setter
  }

public class InsuranceType {
  private String name;
  private String category;
  // getter and setter
}
```

And here is my rule thanks to @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas

```
rule "Example"
when
  $pcr:Premium( $insuranceTypes: insuranceTypes )
  $ins:( InsuranceType( name == "TPD" , category == "D" ) from $insuranceTypes )      
then
  modify( $ins ){ 
        setCategory("A"); 
  }     
end
```

However when running this rule get an exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Update error: handle not found for object: InsuranceType [name=TPD,  category=A]. Is it in the working memory?

Is this occurring because I am checking for the same attribute and also updating it ?
My use case is to replace the value so I have to check for its presence ( category = D and then set it to 'A' )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

InsuranceType is not in working memory -- Premium is. So you need to modify Premium, not insurance type.

There's really not a good way to do this. You could call `update`, but this will refire *all* rules (it's the equivalent of starting over with new data in working memory.)

```
then
  $ins.setCategory("A");
  update( $pcr );
end
```

This might cause side effects like looping or excessive rule triggers.

Alternatively you could modify the Premium by setting the List value:

```
then
  $ins.setCategory("A");
  modify( $pcr ){ 
    setInsuranceTypes($insuranceTypes)
  }     
end
```

... which is clunky but as long as we've not lost the reference to the list should do what we want.

---

Also, not entirely related, but the outer `()` are not necessary on your `$ins` declaration line. This is sufficient:

```
$ins: InsuranceType( name == "TPD" , category == "D" ) from $insuranceTypes
```

I think your original rule had an `exists()` but since you removed that predicate you don't need the parentheses either.

Comment: thanks - will implement your suggestions and post back , thank you